# QGIS TimeManager plugin: how to define the settings from the python console?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

rather than defining interactively the 'Settings' of the QGIS Time Manager plugin, I would like to have the possibility to set them using the python console.  This would save a lot of time in case one wants to animate a long list of rasters.